# How to transpose a list attribute in FME?

Tags: fme-form

Suppose I have one feature per attribute `country` that is linked to a complex list attribute called `stations` with the sub-attributes `name` and `platforms` that looks like this:

```
station{0}.name     Gare du Nord
station{0}.platforms    32
station{0}.name     Hamburg Hbf
station{0}.platforms    12
station{1}.name     Munich Hbf
station{1}.platforms    32
station{2}.name     Frankfurt(Main) Hbf
station{2}.platforms    29
station{0}.name     Utrecht Centraal
station{0}.platforms    16
station{1}.name     Amsterdam Centraal
station{1}.platforms    11
```

The `ListExploder` would give me this (table 1):

| country | *element_index* | name | platforms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | 0 | Gare du Nord | 32 |
| Germany | 0 | Hamburg Hbf | 12 |
| Germany | 1 | Munich Hbf | 32 |
| Germany | 2 | Frankfurt(Main) Hbf | 29 |
| The Netherlands | 0 | Utrecht Centraal | 16 |
| The Netherlands | 1 | Amsterdam Centraal | 11 |

However, I need a transposed version of the table, where a new attribute is created for each combination of index and sub-attribute in the list attribute (table 2):

| country | station{0}.name | station{0}.platforms | station{1}.name | station{1}.platforms | station{2}.name | station{2}.platforms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | Gare du Nord | 32 |  |  |  |  |
| Germany | Hamburg Hbf | 12 | Munich Hbf | 32 | Frankfurt(Main) Hbf | 29 |
| The Netherlands | Utrecht Centraal | 16 | Amsterdam Centraal | 11 |  |  |

As you can see, the number of indices (`stations`) in the list attribute differs per feature (`country`), resulting in a dynamic allocation of attributes.

How can I transpose the contents of a list to get a table structure like in table 2 with FME?

I'm using FME Workbench 2021.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [ListBreaker](https://hub.safe.com/publishers/safe-lab/transformers/listbreaker) transformer (it's a custom transformer from off of the FME Hub). It'll convert your list attributes {1},{2},{3} to attribute_1,_2,_3

[image]

[image]

Hoping this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the solution, the `ListBreaker` looks great, however, I noticed that the attributes are not exposed by the `ListBreaker`. So if I inspect it, there are only the attributes `name` and `platforms` with empty values. When I use the `AttributeExposer`, I can expose the new columns manually (which requies knowing upfront all the names of the attributes). Is there a way to expose them automatically?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's possible for me to do. I can't add an AttributeExposer to the custom transformer because I don't know what the attributes will be called, and it doesn't work if I try to set it programmatically (because FME doesn't know what they will be called). But if you write the data and the attributes are defined in your schema, then the data would get written without needing to be exposed.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. Using the schema upon export sounds like the way to go. Coming from programming languages like Python and R, these hidden and exposed attributes are just not that intuitive.